# Comparing classes up to CGLib enhancement

Tags: java, cglib

I want to test if two values have the same class:

```
x.getClass.equals(y.getClass)
```

However, this comparison should succeed if one (or both) values actually belongs to a class constructed by a CGLib `Enhancer`.

The obvious solution is to search for `$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$...` in class name, remove it, and then compare remaining parts of the class names (and classloaders). Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cglib allows a user to set a `NamingStrategy` which makes replacing the *EnhancerByCGLIB* tag unreliable as a class can be named arbitrarily.

The most reliable way of identifying a cglib class would be to check for the existance of a field `CGLIB$BOUND` which is hard-coded into the library such that the name cannot change. If such a field exists in a class, you need to check if:

1. There are any interfaces implemented. If at least one interface exists, the enhanced class might be this interface. (You might find cglib's `Factory` interface which you must ignore.)
2. There is a super class that is not `java.lang.Object`. Even if an interface is enhanced, there is obviously a super class defined.

As an approximation for a detection algorithm, you could therefore use:

```
static Class<?> original(Class<?> type) {
  try {
    type.getDeclaredField("CGLIB$BOUND");
    if (type.getSuperclass() != Object.class) {
      return type.getSuperclass();
    }
    for (Class<?> iFace : type.getInterfaces()) {
      if (iFace != Factory.class) {
        return iFace;
      }
    }
    return Object.class;
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException ignored) {
    return type;
  }
}
```

Note that cglib allows to generate proxies for classes that also implement several interfaces where the above unrolling would return the super class.